# Task continue with multiple tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a method that uploads one file to server. Right now is working besides any bad coding on the method (Im new to Task library).

Here is the code that uploads a file to server:

```
private async void UploadDocument()

{
    var someTask = await Task.Run<bool>(() =>
    {
        // open input stream
        using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(_cloudDocuments[0].FullName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (StreamWithProgress uploadStreamWithProgress = new StreamWithProgress(stream))
            {
                uploadStreamWithProgress.ProgressChanged += uploadStreamWithProgress_ProgressChanged;

                // start service client
                SiiaSoft.Data.FieTransferWCF ws = new Data.FieTransferWCF();

                // upload file
                ws.UploadFile(_cloudDocuments[0].FileName, (long)_cloudDocuments[0].Size, uploadStreamWithProgress);

                // close service client
                ws.Close();
            }
        }

        return true;

    });

}
```

Then I have a ListBox where I can drag & drop multiple files so what I want to do is to do a FOR LOOP within the ListBox files and then call `UploadDocument();` but I want to first upload 1st file in the listBox then when completed continue with the second file and so on...

Any clue on the best way to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

You should make your `UploadDocument` return `Task`. Then you can await the task in a loop. For example:

```
private async Task UploadAllDocuments()
{
    string[] documents = ...; // Fetch the document names

    foreach (string document in documents)
    {
        await UploadDocument(document);
    }
}

private async Task UploadDocument(string document)
{
    // Code as before, but use document instead of _cloudDocuments[0]
}
```

In fact, your `UploadDocument` can be made simpler anyway:

```
private Task UploadDocument()
{
    return Task.Run<bool>(() =>
    {
        // Code as before
    });
}
```

Wrapping that in an `async` method isn't particularly useful.

(You may well want to change the type to not be `string` - it's not clear what `_cloudDocuments` is.)

In general, you should *always* make an `async` method return `Task` or `Task<T>` unless you *have* to make it return `void` to comply with an event-handling pattern.

Comment: I just did that, one question.. when I call UploadAllDocuments(); its underline with green and when I hover I get: "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call ......" any clue?

Comment: @VAAA: Well we don't have any context of where you're calling this from... we don't even know what kind of application this is... so I can't really help with the code that you haven't shown.

Comment: Its a desktop application, and Im calling UploadAllDocuments() with a click of a botton.

Comment: @VAAA: Okay, so you *could* make the event handler async as well, and await the result of `UploadAllDocuments()` - but if you're not going to do anything after awaiting it (e.g. re-enabling a button) then it may be that you don't need to do anything else.